# OS X Yosemite - no styles at emacs welcome screen

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-yosemite, startup

I have been installed emacs 25.1 on OS X Yosemite.

```
brew cask install emacs
```

Welcome screen looks like:

[image]

But must be similar to

[image]

So no styles, no pictures.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa
```

Gives the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour appears to be triggered by the size of the start up screen.

Making the initial start up screen bigger triggers the "fancy splash screen" for me:

```
emacs -geometry 80x48
```

Or instead add something to the .emacs file...

```
;; initial window
(setq initial-frame-alist
 '((width . 202) ; character
  (height . 60) ; lines
 ))

;; default/subsequent window
(setq default-frame-alist
 '((width . 202) ; character
  (height . 60) ; lines
))
```

(See https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameSize for more details.)

Alternatively, adjust the function which decides what kind of start up screen to display as described here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20976/x11-why-is-the-emacs-logo-image-missing-on-the-welcome-screen

Comment: `emacs -geometry 80x48`, and the link "why is the emacs logo ...." fix my issue. The code `(setq initial-frame-alist ....` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try `brew install emacs --with-cocoa`  ( `brew info emacs` for more options ) Or, tap a different formula like [emacs-plus](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus) that builds Cocoa version by default

Comment: emacs-plus  gives the same result